# Any software to find and replace within zip files?

Tags: zip, unzip

Is there any software that can search and replace trough  archives , zip, tar etc? 
I fund PowerGrep 4 and was so happy to see that it can find the strings but replace fails with bad zip function ,   this one  also fails 
http://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm

is there any way to do this.

I have over 200 archives to update  and is just 1 string within 2-3 files per archive

Comment: you want tool or you want code? as stackoverflow is for programming related question I guess.

Comment: either one ,  shell ,  tool ,   whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

The following Free Mac software will search and replace through zipped files without unzipping/rezipping:

TextWrangler from BareBones (http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)